# Google Endpoints with Auth0 Integration

Tags: google-app-engine, google-cloud-endpoints, swagger-2.0, auth0

I try to use google endpoints authentication with the auth0 integration.

I'm not sure how can i do this, i use the endpoints doc but this is not really complete.
When i deploy it dosen't work.

Thanks for any help

this is my swagger file:

```
swagger: "2.0"
info:
  description: "A simple Google Cloud Endpoints API example."
  title: "Endpoints Example"
  version: "1.0.0"
host: "xxx.appspot.com"
basePath: "/"
consumes:
- "application/json"
produces:
- "application/json"
schemes:
- "https"
paths:
  "/echo":
    get:
      description: "Echo back a given message."
      operationId: "echo"
      produces:
      - "application/json"
      responses:
        200:
          description: "Echo"
          schema:
            $ref: "#/definitions/echoMessage"
      security:
        - auth0_jwk: []
definitions:
  echoMessage:
    properties:
      message:
        type: "string"
  authInfoResponse:
    properties:
      id:
        type: "string"
      email:
        type: "string"
# This section requires all requests to any path to require an API key.
security:
- auth0_jwk: []
securityDefinitions:
  # This section configures basic authentication with an API key.
  api_key:
    type: "apiKey"
    name: "key"
    in: "query"
  # This section configures authentication using Google API Service Accounts
  # to sign a json web token. This is mostly used for server-to-server
  # communication.
  auth0_jwk:
    # Update YOUR-ACCOUNT-NAME with your Auth0 account name.
    authorizationUrl: "https://xxx.auth0.com/authorize"
    flow: "implicit"
    type: "oauth2"
    x-issuer: "https://xxx.auth0.com/"
    # Update this with your service account's email address.
    x-jwks_uri: "https://xxx.auth0.com/.well-known/jwks.json"
```

Comment: What's the exact error you get? Which document/tutorial are you following?

Comment: I get no error the only message is from the command line and says "/echo path not require a apikey". When is deployed i can call the echo path without a error. I follow the google docs for endpoints.

Comment: What are you expecting to happen? What's not working? Which tutorial are you using?

Answer (score 2):

You need to use "x-security" instead of "security". Also, specify audiences for auth0-jwk, which can be any string (Your JWT token audience string has to match "YOUR_AUDIENCE" defined here). For example,

```
    x-security:
      - auth0-jwk:
          audiences:
          - "YOUR_AUDIENCE"
```

You can find an example swagger config at https://github.com/GoogleCloudPlatform/python-docs-samples/blob/master/appengine/flexible/endpoints/swagger.yaml.

Answer (score 0):

I was working on integration between "Google Cloud Endpoints" (ESP) and "Auth0" and I met with some obstacles. At the moment, documentation is not very clear how to get it working, but after some efforts I've implemented it. You can read my topic on Google Groups where I asked a question about an error. I think it can be helpful for you since it describes basic setup in details. Take a look [here](https://groups.google.com/forum/#!topic/google-cloud-endpoints/PSgClngYPCk)